# pytrorchをターミナルでインストールしたが、入っていない

Tags: python, 機械学習, pytorch

## 問題点

TerminalでPytorchをinstallしたが、pip freezeで確認したところ表示されておらず、インストールしたい
使用PCはmacOS Mojave, MacBookPro

## ターミナルでPytorchをinstallしたコードと結果

```
(tf16cpu) bash-3.2$ conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch
WARNING conda.base.context:use_only_tar_bz2(632): Conda is constrained to only using the old .tar.bz2 file format because you have conda-build installed, and it is <3.18.3.  Update or remove conda-build to get smaller downloads and faster extractions.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

All requested packages already installed.
```

## termialでpytrochがintallされているか確認したコードと結果

```
(tf16cpu) bash-3.2$ pip freeze
absl-py==0.7.1
appnope==0.1.0
asn1crypto==0.24.0
astor==0.8.0
astropy==3.1.2
atomicwrites==1.3.0
attrs==19.1.0
backcall==0.1.0
bleach==3.1.0
bokeh==1.1.0
Bottleneck==1.2.1
certifi==2019.6.16
cffi==1.12.3
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
cloudpickle==0.8.1
cryptography==2.6.1
cycler==0.10.0
cytoolz==0.9.0.1
dask==1.2.0
decorator==4.4.0
defusedxml==0.6.0
dill==0.2.9
distributed==1.27.1
entrypoints==0.3
fast-histogram==0.7
gast==0.2.2
glue-core==0.14.2
glue-vispy-viewers==0.11
grpcio==1.21.1
h5py==2.9.0
heapdict==1.0.0
idna==2.8
imageio==2.5.0
ipykernel==5.1.1
ipython==7.5.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
jedi==0.13.3
Jinja2==2.10.1
jsonschema==3.0.1
jupyter-client==5.2.4
jupyter-core==4.4.0
Keras-Applications==1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.0
kiwisolver==1.1.0
locket==0.2.0
Markdown==3.1.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.1.0
mistune==0.8.4
mkl-fft==1.0.12
mkl-random==1.0.2
mock==3.0.5
more-itertools==7.0.0
mpl-scatter-density==0.5
msgpack==0.6.1
nbconvert==5.5.0
nbformat==4.4.0
networkx==2.3
notebook==5.7.8
numpy==1.16.4
olefile==0.46
packaging==19.0
pandas==0.24.2
pandocfilters==1.4.2
parso==0.4.0
partd==0.3.10
pbr==5.1.3
pexpect==4.7.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==6.0.0
plotly==3.8.1
pluggy==0.9.0
prometheus-client==0.6.0
prompt-toolkit==2.0.9
protobuf==3.8.0
psutil==5.6.2
ptyprocess==0.6.0
py==1.8.0
PyAudio==0.2.11
pycparser==2.19
Pygments==2.4.2
PyOpenGL==3.1.1a1
pyOpenSSL==19.0.0
pyparsing==2.4.0
pyrsistent==0.14.11
PySocks==1.6.8
PySoundFile==0.9.0.post1
pytest==4.4.1
pytest-arraydiff==0.3
pytest-astropy==0.5.0
pytest-doctestplus==0.3.0
pytest-openfiles==0.3.2
pytest-remotedata==0.3.1
python-dateutil==2.8.0
pytz==2019.1
PyWavelets==1.0.3
PyYAML==5.1.1
pyzmq==18.0.0
qtconsole==4.4.3
QtPy==1.7.0
requests==2.21.0
retrying==1.3.3
scikit-image==0.15.0
scipy==1.2.1
Send2Trash==1.5.0
six==1.12.0
sortedcontainers==2.1.0
tblib==1.3.2
tensorboard==1.13.1
tensorflow==1.13.1
tensorflow-estimator==1.13.0
termcolor==1.1.0
terminado==0.8.2
testpath==0.4.2
toolz==0.9.0
torch==0.3.0.post4
torchvision==0.3.0
tornado==6.0.2
traitlets==4.3.2
typing==3.6.4
urllib3==1.24.2
wcwidth==0.1.7
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==0.15.4
xlrd==1.2.0
zict==0.1.4
```

Comment: マルチポスト - https://teratail.com/questions/199548

Comment: @Kenza さん、`import torch`でエラーが生じるのでしょうか？　`conda list` の結果も質問文に追記して頂けませんでしょうか。